# When soft keyboard is active, setting text does not work

Tags: java, android, keyboard, sleep

I am writing an android application which displays a string of digits for a fraction of a second. The user would then enter those digits in a text field to see how many of them they were able to read in that flash. However, while the keyboard is open, the string of digits does not appear when the triggering button is pressed. Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

Here is the java code:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void ButtonOnClick(View v){
        Random rand = new Random();

        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        String number = new String();
        for(int i=0; i < 9; i++){
            int num = rand.nextInt(9);
            number = number + Integer.toString(num);
        }

        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        mTextView.setText(number);

        final Runnable makeTextDisapear = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mTextView.setText(null);

                }
            };

            mHandler.postDelayed(makeTextDisapear , 1);

    }

}
```

Edit: I've gotten around this by making an on-screen keypad in the app itself, but I would prefer to use the system keyboard, so I am still interested in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: be aware that [you will only get digits from 0-8 (not a 9)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) when using your code.

I have build some example code for you and tested it. This runs and does what you describe. It hides the keyboard at the right moments and only shows it when the `EditText` is clicked. It does not distract from looking at the numbers. I hope this helps you. Please try the code.

`MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.exampleshowdigits;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button mButton;
    private TextView mTextView1;
    private TextView mTextView2;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private boolean numbersShown;
    private int[] numbers;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mTextView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        mTextView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.showSoftInput(mEditText, 0);
        numbersShown = false;
        numbers = new int[9];
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!numbersShown) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            String number = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
                int num = rand.nextInt(10); //assuming you want 0-9
                numbers[i] = num;
                number += Integer.toString(num); //same as number = number + Integer.toString(num);
            }
            mTextView1.setText(number);
            SystemClock.sleep(500);
            final Runnable makeTextDisapear = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mTextView1.setText("");
                    mButton.setText(getString(R.string.checkresult));
                    mTextView2.setText(getString(R.string.whatdidyousee));
                    mEditText.setText("");
                    numbersShown = true;
                }
            };
            Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            mHandler.postDelayed(makeTextDisapear, 1000);
        }
        else {
            mButton.setText(getString(R.string.shownumbers));
            numbersShown = false;
            int correct = 0;
            String numbersEntered = mEditText.getText().toString();
            for(int i = 0; i < numbersEntered.length(); i++) {
                int num = Character.getNumericValue(numbersEntered.charAt(i));
                if(num == numbers[i]) {
                    correct++;
                }
            }
            mTextView2.setText(correct + " " + getString(R.string.correct));
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/shownumbers"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textview1" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="9"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textview2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`strings.xml`:

```
<string name="shownumbers">Show numbers</string>
<string name="checkresult">Check result</string>
<string name="whatdidyousee">What did you see? Enter here:</string>
<string name="correct">out of 9 correct!</string>
```

Comment: Does the keyboard flicker when the digits appear? Also, thanks for pointing out the lack of '9'. I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: No, I made sure it is down before that, and that it will only get up when the user clicks the `EditText`. Please try the code in an emulator to see for yourself :)

Comment: I probably would have ended up doing this if I hadn't made a numpad as part of the app, but it doesn't quite answer my question. I know I could hide and show the keyboard; I want to know why I can't just leave it up.

Comment: I have edited the answer. (Change both the .java file as well as the layout .xml file!) Now, whenever the keyboard is up, it will stay up without flickering. I hope this is what you have looked for? Otherwise it is device specific, because for my phone and emulators it works.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going for! I actually finished the app last night with the in-app numpad, but I may have to fold this into it. Do you know why what I was doing wasn't working?

Comment: I really don't see why it wasn't working. Maybe because you used just 1 millisecond for delaying the `Runnable`? Maybe because you set the text to `null` instead of `""`? I really can't guess. Maybe it's device specific. Anyway, if my answer helped you, please accept it as an answer to the question :) Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Alright. I was really hoping to find out what was wrong with it, but I'll accept how to fix it.